# Form not being submitted with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I cant get the form to submit using javascript. any advise ?

***Here is the code at the beginning of the form:***

```
<form method="post" name="(Unnamed Form 1)-e449aad6-596f-4806-bbcd-c5186e8b6" action="https://s908318137.t.eloqua.com/e/f2" id="form31" >
<input value="(Unnamed Form 1)-e449aad6-596f-4806-bbcd-c5186e8b6" type="hidden" name="elqFormName"  />
<input value="908318137" type="hidden" name="elqSiteId"  />
<input name="elqCampaignId" type="hidden"  />
```

***Here is the code before*** `<form/>`

```
   <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="complete-form">Please complete the form before submitting.</div>
      <a href="http://s908318137.t.en25.com/e/er?s=908318137&lid=5&elq=<span class=eloquaemail>recipientid</span>" onClick="document.forms["form31"].submit();">» Submit</a>
</form>
```

Comment: what do you mean? you cant see the could i posted ?

Comment: Try onclick instead of onClick

Comment: @NickRoth — HTML attribute names are case insensitive.

Comment: @Quentin Yea, and it should be lower case. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp Edit: Sorry read you comment as cas sensitive.

Comment: @NickRoth — Case intensive means that the case *does not matter* (and W3Schools is a [terrible resource](http://w3fools.org))

Comment: @Quentin I just woke up and misread your comment, sorry :).

Answer (score 0):

Your submit "button" is a link. The JavaScript starts to submit the form, then the link is followed and the request never goes through.

Use a submit button to submit forms.

Replace

```
<a href="http://s908318137.t.en25.com/e/er?s=908318137&lid=5&elq=<span class=eloquaemail>recipientid</span>" onClick="document.forms["form31"].submit();">» Submit</a>
```

With

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: I cant because there is a special button that needs to be displayed here is the URL of the landing page http://offers.thesprinter.ca/TEST

Comment: So apply the CSS to the submit button not the link.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem of the quotes:

```
onClick="document.forms["form31"].submit();"
```

should be

```
onClick="document.forms['form31'].submit();"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of quotes errors on your code. If you have a string delimited by a double quote ", you must selimit the nested strings with single quotes, or escaped quotes.

Furthermore, you should access the document.forms collection by the name property, not the id property.

Answer (score 0):

`document.forms['form31']`  will look for a form with `name="form31"`, while you are using  `id="form31"`.

As a solution you could use `document.getElementById('form31').submit();`.